# GraphQL+Apollo+react:Unable to display data

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Below is the sample client side code using Apollo client.

I am providing data from nodemon express server.

My query works fine in graphiQL.

[image]

```js
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const CounterpartyQuery = gql`
  query data{
        counterparty {
         name
       }
      }
`;

export class ExchangeRates extends React.Component {
   
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.data) // Giving undefined
        return (
            <div>hiii{this.props.data.counterparty.map(x => x.name)}</div>  //Error
        )
    }
}

const counterpartyData = graphql(CounterpartyQuery, { name: 'data' })(ExchangeRates)

export default counterpartyData
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your network call isn't over but the component gets rendered using the variable not available.

You need to use [networkStatus](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-query-data-networkStatus) to see whether the network call is over only then the data would be available to render. Until then you need to show a loader.

So replace

> graphql(CounterpartyQuery, { name: 'data' })

by

```
graphql(CounterpartyQuery, {
        name: 'data' ,
        props : ({data}) => {
            return {
                data,
                isLoading:data['networkStatus']==1 || data['networkStatus']==2 || data['networkStatus']==4
            }
        }
    }),
```

and then use

> this.props.isLoading

variable in the render method to decide whether to show loading or to show the list.

For eg:

```
render() {
        console.log(this.props.data, this.props.isLoading)
        return (
            {this.props.isLoading ? <div>Loading Data</div>:<div>hiii{this.props.data.counterparty.map(x => x.name)}</div>
        }
    )
}
```

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-query-data-networkStatus

Comment: this is reserved keyword in this.props.loading error

Comment: use connect to pass props.

Comment: can you explain in detail how to use connect to pass props in my case ?

Answer (score 0):

Apollo client HOC passes a `loading` prop to each of your queries, you'll need it in almost every case in order to wait for the response before rendering your data (you also need to handle request errors):

```
export class ExchangeRates extends React.Component {

    render() {
        if (this.props.data.loading) {
            return <div> Loading </div>; // rendering an animated loading indicator here is good practice to show an activity
        }
        if (this.props.data.error) {
            return <div> Error </div>;
        }
        return (
            <div>hiii{this.props.data.counterparty.map(x => x.name)}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: After doing what you said , i am getting following error:----TypeError: Cannot read property 'loading' of undefined

Comment: I think naming your query 'data' may cause some issue because this is the default name, try changing the query name or just don't name it

Comment: Removed the name data as query name, but still getting same error

Comment: Is your query working in graphiQL ? There's a difference with the one you show, you added 'data' after 'query'.

Comment: yes the query is working fine, the one without data and with data both are giving same results in server as well as client

Comment: Try to `console.log(this.props)` in render and return an empty <div /> to see what you get.

Comment: I am getting empty object

Comment: There's probably an issue in your [apollo-client config](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/get-started.html)

Comment: I have updated the package but stlll getting same error

Comment: Have you followed the next steps in the link ? Do you wrap your app with `<ApolloProvider client={client}>` ?

Comment: Yeah, i did.. in the apollo docs they are using query component & that worked for me also but if i use HOC then i am getting error ( as you can see)